# Prove that a length-minimizing path in a metric space is injective

Tags: metric-spaces, lipschitz-functions, arc-length, path-connected

Suppose $(X,d)$ is a metric space with the nearest point property and $a,b \in X$ with $a \ne b$. Suppose there is a path of finite length in $X$ from $a$ to $b$ and let $m$ be the infimum of the lengths of all paths from $a$ to $b$.Then, by  Lipschitz reparametrization, there exists a path $g:[0,1] \rightarrow X$ from $a$ to $b$ that satisfies $lth_t(g) = tm ~\forall~t \in [0,1].$ and $g$ is Lipschitz with length $m. lth_t(g)$ represents the length of the function $g$ upto a point $t$.

Prove that $g$ is injective.

**Attempt:**

Suppose $g(a) = g(b)$ where $a,b \in [0,1]$.

I am kind of stuck here. I have no clue how to move forward from here.

Could someone please provide me with a direction to follow.

Comment: What's the "nearest point property"? For all $x\in X$ there is a $y_{nearest}\in X$ with $d(x,z)\geq d(x,y_{nearest})$ for all $z\neq x$ in $X$?

Comment: The nearest point property implies that the metric space $X$ admits a nearest point $z_y  \in X$ to each point $y$ in a metric super space of $X$

Comment: The nearest point property is needed to prove that such $g$ (length-minimizing path) exists; it is not needed to show it's injective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Informally: if a path intersects itself, it forms a loop which we can cut out, thus making it shorter.

Formally: Suppose $g(a)=g(b)$ where $0\le a<b\le 1$. Define 
$$
h(t) = \begin{cases} g(t), \quad & 0 \le t\le a,  \\
g(t-a+b), \quad & a \le t\le 1+a-b
\end{cases} 
$$
Then:

1. $h$ is $m$-Lipschitz. Indeed, the only nonobvious case is $0\le t < a < s \le 1+a-b$. But then
   $$
   |h(t)-h(s)| = |h(t) - h(a) + h(a) - h(s)| \le |h(t) - h(a)| + |h(a) - h(s)|
   \\ =  |g(t) -g(a)| + |g(b) - g(s-a+b)| \le  m(a-t) + m(s-a) = m(s-t)
   $$
   where I write $| \cdot - \cdot |$ instead of $d_X(\cdot, \cdot)$ for brevity.
2. The path defined by $h$ has length at most $m(1+a-b) < m$. This is a contradiction.